# Ban specific file by IP address htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Quick question: how can I use htaccess to bar a specific IP address from a specific file?

Let's say the file is http://mydomain.com/special.pdf

And I have four IP addresses to prevent from accessing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need something like this then

```
<Files special.pdf>
    Deny from 127.0.0.1
    Deny from 127.0.0.2
    Deny from 127.0.0.3
    Deny from 127.0.0.4
</Files>
```